# Can we convert SP2016 master page / page layout to modern communication site style?

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, modern-experience, style

We are using SP2016 on-premise. Our plan is to upgrade to SharePoint online by next year. At the moment we want to convert out existing sites & home pages to modern communication site style. Just like below screenshot.

[image]

I have tried to created some master page and page layout. However since modern view do not have Master page I have no idea how to start.

Is there any resource I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we could do this for SharePoint server 2016.

SharePoint Server 2016 use the classic experience by default, currently only SharePoint server 2019 support modern experience.